# Failed to load cursor from the stream -Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windows-7

I am working on a WPF application. As per requirement , application displaying a  customized   CURSOR object while user  performing the mouse right click  on a data grid. I am using following code to load the Cursor resource.,using datagrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown event

```
 var frameElement = ((FrameworkElement) this.Resources["MoveCursor"]);
                if (frameElement != null)
                {
                    this.Cursor = frameElement.Cursor;
                }
```

I have tested the code on both  Windows 7 and windows 8 machine and found it is working fine. But one of our using this application on a  “Windows 7 Home Premium” machine.
He is facing a “Failed to load cursor from the stream.” While loading the cursor.
The error details are as follows

> System.Windows.Input.Cursor.LoadFromStream(Stream cursorStream) at
>   System.Windows.Input.Cursor..ctor(Stream cursorStream) at
>   System.Windows.Input.CursorConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value) at
>   System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider) at
>   MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension
>   me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)

If anyone have any idea regarding this issue, please help me.  Please guide me way to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Best Regards,

Ranish

Comment: Are the .NET Framework version in these machines different ?

Comment: No. DO you see any other reason?

Comment: I seem to have run into the same problem..Did you find any solution on this?

Comment: I am in Winforms but I guess I am facing the same problem here in loading cursor from stream in windows 7. Any working solution yet?